# How can I align my Left and Right borders that susy calculates?

Tags: susy-compass

I'm trying to design something similar to  GitHubs sliding file browser [image: github sliding file manager]

It's mostly working but im trying to style it and I get this with my borders:

[image: mis-aligned borders]

```
.claim-header, .support-header{
   text-align: center;
   background-color: $argument-review-banners;
  padding: 0.3em;
  font-family: "Jockey One",Arial,Georgia,sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px; // <--- this line breaks it
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

it appears as if the font-size within the div (each one of these rows is a div as it's not really a table, as I'm not doing file browsing per se) is what breaks it, it seems to make the calculation of the width different because of font-size.  I thought that susy caculates widths based on the base-font, not the font of the element.  It's off by 2 pixels and I wonder if this is some sort of rounding error.

I could fix it with *yet another* wrapper div. But I'm wondering what the proper solution would be.

Comment: It's not clear to me how Susy is involved in this, or how you are using it. Can you please provide more context?

Comment: The width of the different divs (see the blue area? the gray area?)  are different (they differ by 2 pixels.  I *do not* specify these widths manually.  They are calculated for me by susy with @include container and (I think) spans my 5 column area.  Maybe the answer is to manually specify widths, but I thought susy would set the width the same in each case (independent of my font-size)

Comment: `.l-main{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    @include container;
 //   @include susy-grid-background;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not related to Susy - you would have the same problem with any em-based width. Susy has no way of knowing that you changed the font size, or want to use a different `em` value - that all gets calculated at the browser level.

The `container` mixin will output the same `em` width each place you use it (given the same settings), but em's are relative to local font-size. That's calculated by the browser, and Susy has no knowledge of it, or control over it. There are several options.

- You can build your grids in `rem` (root em) values instead, on modern browsers.
- You can use the `$container-width` setting to override the calculated width - use px, %, or set the width .
- You can set a single outer container (maybe the `<body>`?) around all these elements.
- You can change the font size in a nested element, rather than on the container.

Comment: First of all: thanks for all your help Eric (most devs dont dosupport) and thanks for an amazing product!  Ok. it looks like what it was wasn't any width specification (the only width I had was on the container--not any of the row divs), it was the padding/margins which were scaling with the font size.  Which is why  even giant changes in font-size (10px v.s. 100px) were making minor modifications in the borders.  Thanks!